# How to get data from all other users in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase database

[image: Firebase database]

I need to make a list of password objects(that contain password, service and username)

Every user/password object is added as an object with a generated ID as a name of that object, I need to retrieve this objects without knowing that user-ID, or the Password object-ID .

Comment: I assume that the keys directly under `/users` (`pXMr...`, `vmAgV...` and `w279v...`) are user IDs. But what are the push IDs under that? E.g. why does the last user have multiple nodes under their account?

Comment: the other ID-s (eg: -L22cbcdr....) are the id-s of the password-object... not the best name, I know. It is an application where the user can store passwords for different accounts, so the last one has multiple nodes because he has multiple accounts(eg: netflix,amazon etc)

Comment: so you are the administrator, and want to retreive data of these users right? maybe change the DB to users parent node and then pushid/data.. pushid/data since you cannot get the usersid and it would be easier, you would use onchildadded

Comment: Ah, so it's a password manager. Got it. Your current structure makes it easy to show a list of passwords for a specific user. Is that what you're trying to do? If so, I'd recommend checking out FirebaseUI, which provides adapters for showing such a list in Android: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

Comment: I am quite new to Android so I was trying an example from a tutorial I was watching. After finishing the app, I wanted to play a little with it and do other stuff(displaying all services, or all usernames(from that service) saved in the database) and I got a little stuck. And yes, the app was supposed to let you see only your passwords(which it does already). I was hoping to implement the other things without having to modify the database.

Comment: yes well if you are the administrator, you not the user in db so doing this `child(user.getUid())` obviously wont work. Im not sure if you can retrieve it somehow that is why I suggested the above